# Anchor tag issue with full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Code like this:

```html
<div>Overall Advance Rating(1 foodees rated)</div>
<a href="#">
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
</a>
```

Here am getting cursor after rating images also. How can i handle cursor until images only. I had tried with width and max width but not able to get solution.

Comment: you could upload the screenshot somewhere else and share the link to that.

Comment: or create some plunker...

Comment: have tried, but this looks like a very bad translation

Comment: The post is very bad explained. We don't know how do you like to reach. I understand almost 3 different problems that you may want to tell us, but I don't know what is the exactly problem that you need help. Please, explain it better.

Comment: sorry guys. I had created screen but to upload it is telling like I should have min 10 reputations. so that am not able to upload img. can u suggest me. how it is

Comment: I don't have much communication in english. So please consider it. I am trying to know like doing this.

Comment: You can share a link to the screenshot, you can upload to http://imgur.com :)

Comment: tq for suggession. now onwards i will

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to only have the pointer cursor over the images and not in between if I understand your question correctly. If so, try this:

```css
a { cursor: default; } 
a img { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div>Overall Advance Rating(1 foodees rated)</div>
<a href="#">
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
</a>
```

Otherwise I believe you might have to try harder to get your question across.

Comment: Hey, Dude tq like this only am asking. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I don't have much communication in english. So please consider it. I am trying to know like doing this.

Comment: @SivaTheBoyYallapu I understand your english might not be good, but I am having trouble understanding what you post.

Answer (score 0):

See comments please, we need to get a better explanation of what you need. If I understand you, you need to individualize img with anchor? Maybe this?

```
 <a href="#">
    <img src="#"/>
 </a>
 <a href="#">
    <img src="#"/>
 </a>
 etc etc
```

Comment: I don't have much communication in english. So please consider it. I am trying to know like doing this.